# Unity AR - 'SortingGroup' does not contain a definition for 'GetSortingGroupByIndex'

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am building a ar application in unity, and i keep getting the following errors

No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRSessionSubsystem is available. Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR project settings.
UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARSession:OnEnable () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.2.7/Runtime/AR/ARSession.cs:341)

No active UnityEngine.XR.XRInputSubsystem is available. Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR project settings.
UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARInputManager:OnEnable () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.2.7/Runtime/AR/ARInputManager.cs:24)

No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystem is available. Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR project settings.
UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.SubsystemLifecycleManager`3<UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystem, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystemDescriptor, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystem/Provider>:OnEnable () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.2.7/Runtime/AR/SubsystemLifecycleManager.cs:68)

i tried different options to fix it like running it on different phones using unity remote, it still showed those errors and a black screen with no camera feed, so i figured why not build it and test it and i kept getting this error

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\EventSystem\Raycasters\Physics2DRaycaster.cs(106,38): error CS0117: 'SortingGroup' does not contain a definition for 'GetSortingGroupByIndex'

I came across it once before and as a i remember it was a collision between the new and old input systems in  unity and I tried changing them back and forth and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was the webgl module in Unity. I had to go to the Unity hub and delete the module (or rather re-install the version of Unity I was working entirely, without the webgl module). Sorry to whoever made it here

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\EventSystem\Raycasters\Physics2DRaycaster.cs(106,38):
> error CS0117: 'SortingGroup' does not contain a definition for
> 'GetSortingGroupByIndex'

In my case the problem was the editor installation.

- Close all editors
- Reinstall unity
- If the error persists, close Unity, remove /Library/PackageCache and reopen Unity
- If the error persists, use the hub to report a bug